# what is correct way to do this php code

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_name = '{$orders}'";
```

but when the value of the `$orders` have a single quote`(')` for example:

```
$orders = "Carlo's shop";
```

the query return an error.

is there any good way to handle this situation?

Comment: Either escape the data or use prepared statements

Comment: Now let's imagine what would happen if it contained `Robert');DROP TABLE customers;--`.

Comment: use pdo insetad of escaping charatcers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PDO with prepared statements. See [reference docs](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_name= :orders');

$query->execute(array('orders' => $orders));
```

---

- You can also look into using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: thank your clever answer, this part `'$orders'` not work for me, but your answer give me an idea how to make my code working.. a very big thanks. happy codding...